# Symfony2.3 PDOHandler too many sessions created on a request

Tags: php, symfony, session, pdo

I am using Symfony2.3 along with its built in [PDOSessionHandler](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) tool for storing sessions in the database. For some reason, it appears that multiple sessions are getting written to the database on each request, and because of this, I am having trouble logging in. Here is my PDO session config:

```
parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table:    Session
        db_id_col:   id
        db_data_col: session_value
        db_time_col: session_time    
services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            dsn:      "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
        calls:
            - [ setAttribute, [3, 2] ] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments:
            - "@pdo"
            - "%pdo.db_options%"
```

Say I make a single GET request to https://acme.mybundle.com/app_dev.php as an anonymous user. Then this is an example of the output that I would see in the `Session` table:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| id | session_value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | session_time |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | X3NmMl9hdHRyaWJ1dGVzfGE6MTp7czozNDoiX3NlY3VyaXR5LnNlY3VyZWRfYXJlYS50YXJnZXRfcGF0aCI7czozODoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hbGxlbmNvLmRldi5hdmF0YXJuZXd5b3JrLmNvbS8iO31fc2YyX2ZsYXNoZXN8YTowOnt9X3NmMl9tZXRhfGE6Mzp7czoxOiJ1IjtpOjE0MTU2MjU4ODQ7czoxOiJjIjtpOjE0MTU2MjU4ODQ7czoxOiJsIjtzOjE6IjAiO30= |   1415625884 |
|  2 | X3NmMl9hdHRyaWJ1dGVzfGE6MDp7fV9zZjJfZmxhc2hlc3xhOjA6e31fc2YyX21ldGF8YTozOntzOjE6InUiO2k6MTQxNTYyNTg4NDtzOjE6ImMiO2k6MTQxNTYyNTg4NDtzOjE6ImwiO3M6MToiMCI7fQ==                                                                                                                     |   1415625884 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

In case you need it, here is my `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User: sha512
    providers:
        main:
            id: acme.user.provider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login_firewall:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

After 1-5 tries I am usually able to log in and no more sessions are created for any future requests. Finally, our server is behind a proxy in case that is relevant. Does anyone know why multiple Sessions are getting written on each Request? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with my ORM `Session` entity. I had the following entry for `$id`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Session
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

//...
}
```

The session's `$id` should not be an integer -- it should be a string (obviously it also should not be auto-incremented. I had many derps after finding this bug). After rewriting the `$id` entry of my class to:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;
```

and running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, everything appears to be working correctly.